# Whenever i try to open docker in my vs code an error occurs

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

The value provided for the setting `docker.host` or environment variable `DOCKER_HOST` is invalid.

It must include the protocol, for example, ssh://myuser@mymachine or tcp://1.2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker context create some-context-label --docker "host=ssh://user@remote_server_ip"

docker context use some-context-label

docker ps
# It works!
```

OR

1.Set (or add) "docker.host": "tcp://localhost:23750" in settings.json in VSCode.

2.Open a SSH tunnel like this in your local machine changing the user and hostname by the remote machine (where the docker daemon is running)
credentials: ssh -NL localhost:23750:/var/run/docker.sock user@hostname.

3.Now, in the docker tab, you will be able to see and attach to containers in the remote machine.

Note that the Remote SSH Extension is not used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Certain references state that the VS Code Docker extension is compatible with podman's exposure of its unix socket connection, `unix:///run/user/$UID/podman/podman.socket`.  However, it may have been deprecated because I have only been able to make it function with `tcp` connection.

This is easy to do, though, and does not require a context, as stated in the answer above. All that's required is running podman as a different type of service.  This is probably most easily achievable at the command line, although it's conceivable you could make an `rc.d`, `upstart`, `sysvinit`, `openrc.service` or `systemd.unit` for it, as well.

The shortest string you could invoke to run the `podman service` from the command line is:

```
$ podman system service tcp:localhost:1234 --time=0 &
```

The `&` ampersand at the end allows you to continue using the shell (otherwise it's tied up until the service is stopped w/ `CTRL-C`).  If you need to stop the service, you can run either `killall podman`, or if your system doesn't have `psmisc [killall]` installed, you can use the `kill` command with `podman`'s current `$PID`, e.g.:

```
$ kill $(ps -a | grep podman | cut -d ' ' -f2)
```

Since the types of service files differ from system to system, and require a bit of background, I will consider them beyond the scope of this answer for now, but let's make a quick shell script that be executed prior to using the VS Code Docker extension:

```
#!/bin/sh
PORT="1234"
HOSTNAME="$(hostname || hostnamectl --static)"
DURATION="$1 || 0"
LOG_LEVEL="error"
LOG_LOCATION="$HOME/.local/containers/log"
LOG_FILENAME="podman_service.log"

if ! [ -d $LOG_LOCATION ]; then do "mkdir -p $LOG_LOCATION; touch $LOG_LOCATION/$LOG_FILE"; done 

/usr/bin/podman system service tcp:$HOSTNAME:$PORT --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL --time=$DURATION --runtime-flag" log-format=file" --runtime-flag" log=$LOG_LOCATION/$LOG_FILENAME"

echo 'podman service started - go use vs code'
```

Save the script in a text file and make it executable with `chmod u+x $FILENAME`, run it with `sh $FILENAME`, and you've got yourself a tcp socket at `tcp:localhost:1234`.  You can set the duration with the first argument after the script, e.g. `sh $FILENAME`, which I believe is in milliseconds, e.g. `$FILENAME 5000` would run for 5 seconds. Otherwise, the script defaults to running indefinitely if run without arguments.

The log file and level are all optional.    Podman will display real-time feedback in the terminal, the `--log-level=$LOG_LEVEL` flag adjusts the level of verbosity, the range is: `debug, info, warn, error, fatal or panic (default: "warn")` and (not in the docs) there is `trace` for a stack trace log (extremely verbose).

If you'd rather not have to run a command every time, you could create your own unit file.  Copy `/usr/lib/systemd/user/podman.service` somewhere you can edit it, like your `~/Documents` folder.  Rename it to `podman-tcp.service` to differentiate it from `podman.service`, and make the following changes:

add `tcp:localhost:1234 --time=0` at the end of `ExecStart=` line, and maybe change the description, with something like `tcp socket`, etc.

```
# podman-tcp.service user systemd unit file
# /usr/lib/systemd/user/podman-tcp.service
[Unit]
Description=Podman tcp socket API Service
Requires=podman.socket
After=podman.socket
Documentation=man:podman-system-service(1)
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=exec
KillMode=process
Environment=LOGGING="--log-level=info"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman $LOGGING system service tcp:localhost:1234 --time=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Copy the new unit file to the systemd user unit folder:

```
$ sudo cp podman-tcp.service /usr/lib/systemd/user/.
```

Reload all the units:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And enable + run the service file simultaneously:

```
$ systemctl --user enable --now podman-tcp.service
```

Then, when you check `systemctl --user status podman-tcp.service`, it should show you something like this (keyword is **active**):

```
lines 1-18/18 (END)...skipping...
● podman-tcp.service - Podman tcp socket API Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/podman-tcp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-02-19 01:48:50 PST; 36s ago
       Docs: man:podman-system-service(1)
   Main PID: 225757 (podman)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 38163)
     Memory: 10.6M
        CPU: 51ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/podman-tcp.service
             ‣ 225757 /usr/bin/podman --log-level=info system service tcp:localhost:1234 --time=0

Feb 19 01:48:50 endpoint-bob systemd[18905]: Starting Podman API Service...
Feb 19 01:48:50 endpoint-bob systemd[18905]: Started Podman API Service.
Feb 19 01:48:50 endpoint-bob podman[225757]: time="2022-02-19T01:48:50-08:00" level=info msg="/usr/bin/podman filtering at log level info"
Feb 19 01:48:50 endpoint-bob podman[225757]: time="2022-02-19T01:48:50-08:00" level=info msg="Found CNI network podman (type=bridge) at /home/avery/.config/cni/net.d/87-podman.conflist"
Feb 19 01:48:50 endpoint-bob podman[225757]: time="2022-02-19T01:48:50-08:00" level=info msg="Setting parallel job count to 37"
Feb 19 01:48:50 endpoint-bob podman[225757]: time="2022-02-19T01:48:50-08:00" level=info msg="using API endpoint: 'tcp:localhost:1234'"
Feb 19 01:48:50 endpoint-bob podman[225757]: time="2022-02-19T01:48:50-08:00" level=info msg="API service listening on \"127.0.0.1:1234\""
```

Once it's started, it should stay running indefinitely, and even survive a reboot. The way it's written, though, if you need the unix socket for something, you have to stop the `podman-tcp.service` and re-start the `podman.service` the same way. (To be fair, running `podman system service` from the command line also disables the unix socket, but it is not as difficult to stop and start - it's really up to you what you think is easiest / makes the most sense for your situation).

**Troubleshooting**:  If you have any issues getting VS Code to attach to `localhost`, try the loopback IP address `127.0.0.1` - maybe `localhost` isn't defined in your `/etc/hosts` file.

If you want podman's tcp socket to be available on your LAN, give it your hostname or your computer's IP address instead of localhost.

You can make the `$PORT` whatever you'd like, rootless podman's range is between `1069 - 65536`.  `1234` is just an example.

**References**:

1. [Podman quick manual](https://www.mankier.com/1/podman)
2. [Github issue: stack trace log level feature
   request](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/4854)